# Squash - what is wrong with my grip?

Tags: squash

Whenever I hit the ball hard especially when I miss the sweet spot my racket is dislodged slightly in my hand. The problem is intensified when my hand becomes sweaty and the accuracy of my shots suffers greatly.

I started wearing a sweatband which did remedy the problem a little, however the grip is still far from satisfactory.

How do I achieve a better grip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping something over the base grip of your racket? Some people use gauze and can also buy overgrips which are meant to absorb moisture and provide a tacky feel. If you tend to play with loose hands overgrips can really help. These things I am describing (gauze and overgrips) are generally very thin and don't increase the overall size of the grip that drastically.

Comment: I have done some research today on grip size and since my finger tips were resting against the palm, as I understand with proper grip size they should just touch the palm ever so lightly. As you suggested I have put a couple of over-grips - they're indeed very tacky - it solved the girth problem as well. Will try the new set-up tomorrow and report results.

Comment: added thickness really solved the problem

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear you got it sorted out!